# What does "manga" truly mean in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

In English the word "manga" is used to refer to Japanese comics. I would like to know if this word is similar to "anime", where westerns use it only for "Japanese" animation (in a broad sense since several "Japanese" animations are produced in Japan but animated on Korea or other country) or does it mean comics in general? Is a fanfic japanese comic a "manga" or does it have to be paid and officially released to be "manga"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

漫画/マンガ in Japanese is close to *comic* in English. It's a generic term that safely includes, for example, *Peanuts* and *Spider-Man*. It doesn't have to be released commercially, and even a 10-year-old boy can draw 漫画. It usually consists of many pages and frames (コマ), but when a picture has a balloon and a "story", people sometimes call it a [(1コマ)漫画](https://store.line.me/stickershop/product/1018984/ja).

アニメ also is a word that includes foreign cartoons such as Disney's movies.

Comment: Very interesting how the word アニメ includes any cartoon then in other cultures refers to japanese cartoons because the word itself is japanese. I think it's the same with 刀 and other words about swords. I'll do a topic about it if there isn't any yet.

Comment: No, no, no, clearly _manga_ is the feminine form of _mango_.  So it must be a fruit. `</badum_tish>`

Answer (score 0):

Manga has a much broader meaning traditionally. For example, every year Hokusai, the Japanese artist, would create a sketch book of drawings in response to his students constant question of  “what should we be drawing?”. I have that multi-volume set at home. Hokusai drew every aspect of Japanese culture and society of his day as well as imaginary creatures. Not a comic book at all.

Comment: Are you talking about [ this sketchbook called 北斎漫画](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E6%96%8E%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB).? I think normally manga contains more plot than mere sketchbook.

Comment: @kimi Tanaka - there are two meanings of 漫画 in Japanese dictionaries